# How to check the state of element in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Trying the below code to get the total number of number elements in the different pages. The while condition is getting true and the loop gets executed, but after reaching the last page, the condition is not getting false.

I'm iterating the loop by clicking on "next" button till it is enabled and have to stop the loop execution when this condition becomes false.

Please advice and help me out here. Have tried isEnabled(), isDisplayed as well.

**Last Page HTML mark-up**

```
<ul class="pagination-list">
    <li class="disabled">
        <a>
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Selenium-**

```
 while(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[not(contains(@class, 'disabled'))]/a/span[(contains(@class, 'icon-next'))]"))!= null)
    {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
        driver.findElement(By.className("icon-next")).click();
        ActiveEnrollUserCounts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='usersList']/tbody/tr"));
        uTotal = uTotal + ActiveEnrollUserCounts.size();
    }
    System.out.println("Active Enrolled Users Count: " +uTotal);
```

Comment: `Next` button not always becomes disabled in this case... Does class name of the `Next` button changes after you reach last page?

Comment: @Andersson- Yes! The class name of <li> for the last page changes to disabled and there is no href for <a> tag. Also please check the updated code, have added the HTML for the same. Thanks in advance!